# Understanding the concepts of word embedding in GPT-2

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I have a program that calculate the word embedding using GPT-2 specifically the `GPT2Model` class:

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2Model.from_pretrained('gpt2')
caption = "this bird is yellow has red wings"
encoded_caption = tokenizer(caption, return_tensors='pt')
input_ids = encoded_caption['input_ids']

with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(input_ids)
word_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

I have a few questions about this:

1. When calculating the word embedding using `outputs.last_hidden_state`, does this mean that the word embedding only uses the token embedding and positional embedding of GPT-2, without feeding them to the decoder blocks after that ?
2. Is this embedding also known as contextualized embedding ?
3. How does this embedding better than RNN architectures, such as LSTM or bidirectional-LSTM embedding ?

Comment: Hi @abcd, welcome to the site. If you find the answers to your question useful, please consider upvoting them. Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one clarification: GPT-2 does not deals with words, but with tokens. A token represents a string from a letter to a full word. You can check the vocabulary file [here](https://huggingface.co/gpt2/raw/main/vocab.json). The tokens in the vocabulary where defined by an algorithm called byte-pair encoding (BPE); you can check the questions about BPE in this very site.

Now, the answers to your questions:

> 1. When calculating the word embedding using outputs.last_hidden_state, does this mean that the word embedding only uses the token embedding and positional embedding of GPT-2, without feeding them to the decoder blocks after that ?

No, it means the opposite: it uses the states of the last layer of the Transformer decoder, after going through all the layers of the model. Note that these embeddings are close to the fixed token embeddings. You may obtain more useful embeddings if you concatenate the hidden states of the last few layers.

> 2. Is this embedding also known as contextualized embedding ?

Well, your embeddings are contextual indeed. However, you are computing them with a causal language model, which for each token prediction only takes into account the previos tokens. Therefore, the context used for each token embedding is the part of the sentence that came before that token, not the following part.

> 3. How does this embedding better than RNN architectures, such as LSTM or bidirectional-LSTM embedding ?

LSTMs are also causal, so they also only take into account the previous tokens as context. Bidirectional LSTMs are a concatenation of the results of LSTMs in opposite directions; in this case, you obtain context from both sides, but such context has not been computed "at once", but in separate halfs (one half is computed from the context before each token, the other half from the context after it), therefore is not actually fully contextual.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is a stupid question, about question 2
, [this line](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3eddda1111f70f3a59485e08540e8262b927e867/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py#L839) of the GPT2Model class only uses the token embedding and positional embedding for calculation, where in the code that these embeddings go through all the layers of the decoder block, can you explain ? Thanks

Comment: That's just the initialization of variable `hidden_states`. After that, it is overwritten after computing each layer [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3eddda1111f70f3a59485e08540e8262b927e867/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py#L899), then it's applied a linear projection [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/3eddda1111f70f3a59485e08540e8262b927e867/src/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py#L914).

Comment: Thank you, I understand now, another question is that when you said `Note that these embeddings are close to the fixed token embeddings`, I thought they should be the same as the [vocabulary file](https://huggingface.co/gpt2/raw/main/vocab.json) ? I use the pretrained model and not fine-tuning the model ? Can you explain ? Thanks

Comment: The last hidden states are used to predict tokens. The distance (i.e. dot product) from the last hidden states to the tokens embeddings from the embeddings table is used to compute the probability distribution of the tokens to generate. Therefore, the last hidden states -by definition- should be close to the fixed token embeddings.

Comment: Thanks ! About question 2, I found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1528#issuecomment-542726214) mentions that `hidden_states[0]` is equal to `word_embeddings(inputs) + positional_embeds(outputs)`. I'm quite confused, can you help clarify this for me ? Thanks

Comment: I think that's a typo and they actually meant `word_embeddings(inputs) + positional_embeds(inputs)`